# Need an autonomous transaction procedure for below scenario

Tags: plsql, pragma

On any report generation screen (front-end), after filling the form with desired data, on submit, we call some procedure that generates report.
    But before this data is sent for report generation, i have a table in which the entered form data has to be inserted. 
    And this has to be done using autonomous transaction procedure. Consider below example tables and suggest.

```
Example:
Table in which logs are inserted : rep_log_tabl  (user_id, app_id, cur_date, param1, param2, param3,.... param10)
Table which has app_id details: rep_app_tabl (app_id, field_name, X,X,X,X)
Table which has user_details : rep_user_detl (user_id,X,X,X,X,X)

Example form:
From Date: 1/1/2016 (Text)
To Date: 1/15/2016 (Text)
Type: Actual / Latest (drop down field)

and the table rep_log_tabl holds data like below:
user_id |   app_id  |   cur_date    |   param1  |   param2  |   param3  |   param4  | . . . . | param10 |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
U1234   |   AXX-01  |   1/27/2016   |   1/1/2016|   1/15/2016|  Actual  |   null    | . . . . | null    |

App_id and user_id is dependent on some parnt group from which the user logs in.
```

Comment: Why do you need an autonomous transaction ? Why not a simple transaction ?

Comment: I think simple transaction would do, wanted to know the use of autonomous transaction in this case..

Comment: There is an explanation of `AUTONOMOUS_TRANSACTION Pragma` together with a few examples in the documentation here: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14261/autonotransaction_pragma.htm there are also many examples in the internet, for example here https://oracle-base.com/articles/misc/autonomous-transactions. Please study these links and then explain what is unclear to you ?